# Не добавляется/ не возвращается запись в SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, maui

Пытаюсь реализовать регистрацию в приложении (пока на локальном уровне), после регистрации приложение должно перейти в сессию, где уже вывести информацию об аккаунте. Проблема в том, что при получении записи из бд возвращается `null` объект. Не знаю, в чем проблема, то-ли при регистрации объект в бд не добавляется, то ли неправильно получаю. Гляньте, пожалуйста:

Завершение регистрации:

```
private async void btnRegister_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Database.SmartYardDB db = new Database.SmartYardDB();
        Models.Tables.Users user = new Models.Tables.Users()
        {
            Name = profile.Name,
            Adress = profile.Adress,
            Password = profile.Password,
            Phone = profile.PhoneNumber,
            ImageResource = "user_no_image.png"
        };

        Console.WriteLine(profile.Password); //эти данные выводятся в консоли корректно
        Console.WriteLine(profile.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(profile.PhoneNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(profile.Adress);

        await db.addUser(user);
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//session/NewsPage");
    }
```

Получение в сессии:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    Database.SmartYardDB db = new Database.SmartYardDB();
    var res = await db.getMainUserInfo();
    if (res == null) Console.WriteLine("res is null"); //выводится это сообщение
    lbName.Text = res.Name;
    lbAdress.Text = res.Adress;

}
```

Методы базы данных:

```
public async Task init()
    {
        if (db is not null)
        {
            return;
        }

        db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.Database.DatabasePath, Constants.Database.Flags);
        await db.CreateTableAsync<Models.Tables.Users>(); //может неправильно таблицы добавляю?
        await db.CreateTableAsync<Models.Tables.Messages>();
        await db.CreateTableAsync<Models.Tables.Polls>();
        }

public async Task<Models.Tables.Users> getMainUserInfo()
        {
            await init();
            return await db.Table<Models.Tables.Users>().Where(i => i.userId == 0).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

public async Task addUser(Models.Tables.Users user)
        {
            await init();
            await db.InsertAsync(user);
        }
```

Cпасибо!

Comment: А userId у вас точно 0 в добавленной записи?

Comment: @PavelMayorov по идее я же добавляю ее, как первую, полагаю, что да

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, `InsertAsync()`, добавил первый элемент, под `userId` равном 1